# magento 2 graphic issue on product page

Tags: magento2, frontend, swatches, product-page

If I click on "buy" with an empty field, I get this message in the wrong position. Where can I find the template to edit this? Is there a solution? I've been troubling on it for days.

Try this here https://mobiroloshop.com/motion

[image]

**SOLUTION:**

For anyone struggling with this, I added this script in my footer and it works like a charm. Seems like it's a magento bug, this is just a work-around but does the job for now, hope Magento will soon fix this.

```
<script>
require([
    "jquery"
], function($){
    $(document).ready(function () {
        'use strict';
        var validationErrorMoved = false;
        $('#product-addtocart-button').click(function() {
            if (!validationErrorMoved) {
                $('.swatch-attribute').each(function() {
                    var attrId = $(this).attr('attribute-id');
                    var validationElement = $('input[name="super_attribute['+attrId+']"]').get(0);
                    $(validationElement).appendTo(this);
                });
                validationErrorMoved = true;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no template. Swatches are generated by javascript in:

```
vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/frontend/web/js/SwatchRenderer.js
```

Comment: Thanks @nuovecode, but I did not find nothing in that file to solve the issue